# can't update entity Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

Trying to update my entity, unfortunately didnt use Doctrines generate CRUD feature (have to change stuff I didnt write). 
I am finally getting data into my form, but it just won't save the changes (also, it doesn't create a new entity as one might suspect).
When I click 'save', I always return to the page where I have my form to edit the entity.
Checked if method is POST, it is.

```php
 if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
```

doesn't seem to do anything, how can that be?

Here's the rest of my action:

```php
  /**
     * Updates.
     *
     * @Route("/offerweekchange/{offerid}", name="offerweekchange")
     * @Template("")
     */
    public function offerweekchangeAction(Request $request, $offerid)
    {
        $request = $this->get('request');
        if ($offerid) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('AlexanderBuerkleShopBundle:Promotion')->findOneBy(array('id' => $offerid));

            $form = $this->createForm(new OfferWeekChangeType(), $entity);
           # \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($request->getMethod());
            if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
                if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

                    $form->bind($request);
                    if ($form->isValid()) {
                        $em->flush();
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offerweeklist'));
                        }
                    }
                }

            return $this->render('AlexanderBuerkleShopBundle:OfferWeekList:offerweekchange.html.twig',
                array('form' => $form->createView(), 'offerid' => $offerid, 'entity' => $entity));

        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a working sample of your code:

```php
public function offerweekchangeAction(Request $request, $offerid)
    {
        if ($offerid) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('AlexanderBuerkleShopBundle:Promotion')->findOneBy(array('id' => $offerid));

            $form = $this->createForm(new OfferWeekChangeType(), $entity);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

           # \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($request->getMethod());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
               $em->persist($entity);
               $em->flush();
               return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offerweeklist'));
            }
            return $this->render('AlexanderBuerkleShopBundle:OfferWeekList:offerweekchange.html.twig',
                array('form' => $form->createView(), 'offerid' => $offerid, 'entity' => $entity));

        }
    }
```

Secondly, you have several mistakes here, so let's analyse them one by one:

1:

```
if ($offerid) {
```

your code does nothing on the else branch.

2:

```
$request = $this->get('request');
```

you already have the request parameter injected into the action. This line is redundant.

3:

```
$form->bind($request);
```

This is deprecated since 2.3. Use $form->handleRequest($request) instead.

4:

```
$em->flush();
```

You are flushing the entity manager, but nothing is persisted, so nothing will happen. you have to persist the entity first with $em->persist($entity)

5:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
```

The method $form->isValid() checks for this also, so checking for post is redundant.

That's it. Hope it helped.

Comment: First of all, thanks al lot! Unfortunately, it still won't work as I want it to. First goal: i want to display the existing data in my form. this doesnt work anymore with your code. Second goal: make small changes to the existing data and save it, then return to my list. With your code, Í can fill in changes, but I have to re-enter everything. And after saving it, I stilll won't get redirected to the list.

Comment: nevermind. Just found out that the template i used was the problem. Rendereing the form correctly did the trick. Thanks again for your answer and patience.

Comment: btw, no need to persist the entity when you're updating. $em->flush(); seems to be enough.

Comment: @pcm Burnt is correct, no need to persist when updating, only when creating.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue here is with the AbstractType which define your form **OfferWeekChangeType**).

In order to map the form data on the entity you need to set the 'data_class'.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(
        array(
            'data_class' => ' Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product',
        )
    );
}
```

then inside your controller you need to invoke :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

This will bind the request to your form.

Only when you invoke:

```
$form->isValid()
```

The data from the form (if valid) will be mapped on the entity.

```
$em->persist($entity);
```

in this case is superflus because Doctrine **UnityOfWork already 'knows' the entity from when you got it from the repository**. Just invoke

```
$em->flush($entity);
```

As a side note remember that flushing only the needed entity is preferable (when possible) the flush the entire UnityOfWork in order to avoid unexpected behaviours.

Regards.